# Rails 3.2, virtual accessor and deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, virtual-attribute

I'm really confused about virtual attributes in Rails 3.2 and all my research haven't help making things clearer.

```
# input model
class Input < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Attributes --------------------
  attr_accessible :title, :parent
  attr_accessor :parent

  def parent=(id)
    wrtite_attribute(:parent, id.to_i)
    self.parent = id.to_i
    self[:parent] = id.to_i
    @parent = id.to_i # seems to be the only one working. Why?
  end

end

# inputs controller
class InputsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @input = Input.new({
      start_date: @current_scope_company.creation_date,
      parent: 'bla'
    })

    @input.parent = 'bla'
    @input[;parent] = 'bla'

  end
end

# inputs table
create_table "inputs", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at",                        :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                        :null => false
end
```

Above, I have compiled pretty much all the alternatives I found on the internet. It is NOT the code I run, just couple versions of the same thing. Though, whatever I try, I get the following warning:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute 'parent'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use 'attr_writer' etc.`

Sometimes, I even get a `stack level too deep`. I'd love to understand how attributes work.

1/ `attr_accessor` is `attr_writer` plus `attr_reader` right? Why am I asked to use `attr_writer` in the warning?

2/ How am I supposed to write attributes from the model (and why)

3/ How am I supposed to write attributes from the controller (and why)

Thanks a lot!

**Update**

After further test, it looks like the proper way to do it is `@parent = id.to_i`. I would still love to get explanation why. I'm really confused why `self.` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Atttr_accessor should be fine. So in your model, it looks like you're trying to do the same thing in four different ways:

```
def parent=(id)
  write_attribute(:parent, id.to_i)
  self.parent = id.to_i
  self[:parent] = id.to_i
  @parent = id.to_i            # <- all these are redundant and scary
end
```

(Furthermore, in your controller it looks like you're also trying to do the same thing in different ways, unnecessarily.) Also, I'm pretty sure the syntax 'def parent=(id)' is only for real attributes. Looking at [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised) and from my own experience, you just do something like this for a virtual attribute:

```
def parent
  @id.to_i
end
```

Where is "id" coming from that's supposed to go into 'parent'? Virtual attributes have to somehow related to something that's actually being stored in the db, either through a real attribute or through an association's real attribute. If you explain a bit more of what parent is actually supposed to be calculated from, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: This is not the code I run, just four exemples of the same thing I've run across. I'm just confused what is what and which to use. I watched this railscast, but it will still throw the deprecation warning. `self.parent` being the problem.

Comment: haha oh okay. so what exactly is parent supposed to be calculated from? where is id coming from?

Comment: also, the reason youre getting the warning is parent=(id) tries to create a real attribute, which isnt what you want to do. try the method i gave above.

Comment: parent is a field in my form that let's me define a relationship. It is an unconventional way to use relationships, but I'm kinda forced by the existing structure. It receives an id do some magic to set the relationship and that's it. I don't need it in the DB because the relation ship is already expressed somewhere else (it is not a belongs_to relationship).

Comment: In the railscast, price_in_dollar is not a real attribute. The real one is price_in_cents. parent= isn't technically limited to real attributes, it is a method like any other. attr_writer or attr_accessor is creating this function in the back from what I understand.

Comment: yeah so if its a relationship, parent isnt an attribute. parent_id would be the attribute (but thats not in your schema). why dont you do a hidden field like f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => x.id. Or, merge the attributes when you're creating the input, like input_param.merge(parent: @parent)

Comment: also just saw that its not a belongs_to so there wouldnt be a parent_id in the table. could you actually give your models and form so we have an idea of what you're talking about?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but it is not the point of my question. It is not important how/why I use it, I just want to understand the deprecation warning and how I can set virtual parameters in ruby/rails.

Comment: So my point is that I'm not convinced you're using virtual params correctly and there's probably a better way (but since you're not explaining the deetz, who knows). Did you even try the method I suggested in my answer? Furthermore, attribute=(incoming_attr) I believe does usually refer to ActiveRecord attributes - see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html; unless you elsewhere somehow define parent in the model, which it doesn't look like you do. And furthermore, if you explained the context, we could probably help you write a better method for parent anyway.

Comment: anyway, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080868/setting-getting-virtual-attributes-in-rails-model. notice how when they do attr=(blah), they are also defining attr as a method itself.

Comment: write_attribute is used in both your links, still it is deprecated. Your suggestion is a method that return a model attribute, not setting one. Again not my question.